# Get the list of defined currencies

Tags: soql, multi-currency

In a multi currency org, how do I get the list of currencies configured in the org?

I need the label and the ISO Code. I dont see the label in the DatedConversionRate object. So can someone tell me where I do get them?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **[`CurrencyType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm)**:

> Represents the currencies used by an organization for which the multicurrency feature is enabled.

Comment: I see the currency code on that object but not the currency name